# using seq in bash commands

Tags: bash, seq

I have a script "epsmat_hdf5_merge.py" that merges contents of several files. However, those files are in their individual folders, each named with a number (0001 0002 ...). I am using the most primitive method to identify the files in the folders:

```
epsmat_hdf5_merge.py q0001/eps0mat.h5 q0002/eps0mat.h5 q0003/eps0mat.h5 0004/eps0mat.h5 q0005/eps0mat.h5 q0006/eps0mat.h5 q0007/eps0mat.h5 q0008/eps0mat.h5 q0009/eps0mat.h5 q0010/eps0mat.h5
```

Note here that the command is "epsmat_hdf5_merge.py" followed by all the .h5 files in their respective folders.

I cannot use a simple seq loop because

```
for i in seq`1 999`
do
epsmat_hdf5_merge.py q$i/eps0mat.h5
```

will simply do the following:

```
    epsmat_hdf5_merge.py q0001/eps0mat.h5
    epsmat_hdf5_merge.py q0002/eps0mat.h5
    epsmat_hdf5_merge.py q0003/eps0mat.h5
...
```

which is only one file followed by the .py script. The merge script hence cannot merge anything at any step.

Any idea how to handle this?

Endnote:

Also, if we change the total number of folders (999) now to a variable (var), how will the syntax be like considering bracket expansion has trouble managing the $var?

Comment: Could you please post a code that works as you describe? The current doce does not do what you state it does, so we cannot advice about any improvement because we don't know what are you doing.

Comment: Again, the code you posted does not do what you say. Please, post the real code you are using to get your actual results along with the expected results.

Comment: the actual code I'm using is the first set, it gets what I want but it is clumsy. The second code field is a general idea of what I want, but it does not work because it is not pooling all the xxx/eps0mat.h5 behind one single epsmat_hdf5_merge.py
Can't see which part is unclear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brace Expansion.

```
for i in q{0001..999}; do 
  echo epsmat_hdf5_merge.py $i/eps0mat.h5
done
```

Using `find` to process in batch. `bash4+` only

```
find q{0001..999}/ -type f -name '*.h5' -exec echo epsmat_hdf5_merge.py {} +
```

If your bash is lower than `bash4+` try.

```
find q[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ -type f -name '*.h5' -exec echo epsmat_hdf5_merge.py {} +
```

---

Edit: As mentioned in the comments a `variable` being used in the

```
{0001..999}
```

to

```
{0001..$var}
```

However it does not work in bash, afaik It only works on `zsh` because brace expansion happens before variable expansion does.

A work around is to use a c style for loop.

```
var=999
array=()

for ((i = 1; i <= var; i++)); do
  printf -v num '%04d' "$i"
  array+=("q$num/")
done

find "${array[@]}" -type f -name '*.h5' -exec echo epsmat_hdf5_merge.py {} +
```

- Remove the `echo` if you like what is the output.

Comment: Thanks Jetchisel, but this command is still doing `epsmat_hdf5_merge.py 0001/eps0mat.h5 ;epsmat_hdf5_merge.py 0002/eps0mat.h5;....` instead of `epsmat_hdf5_merge.py 0001/eps0mat.h5 0002/eps0mat.h5 .....`

Comment: Do you want to process everything at once?

Comment: yes. the script is in essence merging all the files given in the command

Comment: Please update your question and add and clarify what you wanted to do.

Comment: updated the question to clarify the issue. Do you mind explaining what each part of the find command does? It is not showing any output and trying to understand which part is not working.

Comment: I think the zero-padding on brace expansion requires `bash` v4+ by the way.

Comment: I think OP only wants to run his `epsmat_hdf5_merge.py` script ONE time, and that one execution should have all the filenames as parameters to the single execution.

Comment: @Jacek do you have bash3 or higher?

Comment: I'm running things on the school's server, How to check? the usual seq -w works fine though.
and Yes, Mark understands it correctly

Comment: @MarkSetchell that is what find is for, to process in batch yes?

Comment: You will run OP's program once for each file, i.e. lots of times. OP wants to run once only `epsmat_hdf5_merge.py q{0001..999}/...`

Comment: I don't think it's the padding issue. The command looks for files qxxxx/eps0mat.h5, but does nothing when those files are found. Both the bash 4+ and bash 4- solutions are giving the same output, which is nothing..

Comment: btw, I updated my question such that now the folders are named qxxxx instead of xxxx since this is what I have. It shouldn't affect the syntax much i suppose.

Comment: The command with q added now gives the following error: `find: q{0001..0030}/: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Jetchisel, I debugged a little and turns out there was a mistake in my files. I was running the command in the wrong folder. Your first code `find q{0001..999}/ -type f -name '*.h5' -exec echo epsmat_hdf5_merge.py {} +` works. Now, if I have a variable instead of 999, like `var=999; find q{0001..$var}/ ........`, the system reflects that it has a problem finding the files q{0001..}. How does the syntax work to include the variable?

Comment: Unfortunately that works only on `zsh` in bash you can use a `c-style` for-loop and save it in an array. Or... using eval...

Comment: Something like: `var=999; mapfile -t array < <(eval echo q{0001..$var}/); find "${array[@]}" -type f ...`

Comment: Which gives an error, at least on this side. I have updated the answer.

Comment: The code in the answer works, but the sequence of $var in the array is jumbled for some reason:
`epsmat_hdf5_merge.py ./q0011/eps0mat.h5 ./q0019/eps0mat.h5 ./q0028/eps0mat.h5 ./q0002/eps0mat.h5 ./q0030/eps0mat.h5 ./q0008/eps0mat.h5 ./q0015/eps0mat.h5 ./q0013/eps0mat.h5 ./q0003/eps0mat.h5 ./q0001/eps0mat.h5 ./q0009/eps0mat.h5 ./q0027/eps0mat.h5 ./q0029/eps0mat.h5 ./q0016/eps0mat.h5 ./q0018/eps0mat.h5 ./q0022/eps0mat.h5 ./q0014/eps0mat.h5 ./q0006/eps0mat.h5 ./q0004/eps0mat.h5 ./q0020/eps0mat.h5 ./q0007/eps0mat.h5 ./q0024/eps0mat.h5 ./q0025/eps0mat.h5 ......`

Comment: This is what I get when running that:  http://sprunge.us/ZNkhlw

Comment: Interesting... But this error is definitely not because of the commands. I'll figure this out on my own then.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think you are looking for

```
epsmat_hdf5_merge.py q{0001..0030}/eps0mat.h5
```

You should adjust 0001 and 0030 to the actual numbers you are interested in. There are also options for missing numbers, or extra ones. As long as brace expansion works, which won't be the case in old bash versions.